# c++ : libcurl request in file format error

Tags: c++

i'm a beginner in c++. I want to send request to a API, for this i use libcurl, and stock the response on a string and copy the string in a file. it is my test file  :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <fstream>

int MyCurlObject::curlWriter(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string *buffer) {
  int result = 0;
  if (buffer != NULL) {
    buffer->append(data, size * nmemb);
    result = size * nmemb;
  }
  return result;
}

int main (){
    std::string url = "https://www.google.com/";
    std::string content;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(!curl)
    {
        std::cerr << "impossible d'initialiser curl." << std::endl;
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &MyCurlObject::curlWriter);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
    const CURLcode rc = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if( rc != CURLE_OK ) {
        std::cout << "Error from cURL: " << curl_easy_strerror(rc) << std::endl;
    }
    std::ofstream file(fileName);

    if(!file){
        std::cerr << "can't open this file : " << fileName << std::endl;
    }
    file << content;

    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

My files contain all of my string, but line in file not contain end of line symbol ( i display all of symbol with notepade++ and i just see CR in end of line )  and if i make this :

```
std::ifstream file(name);
if(file)
{
    std::string crash;
    int nbrOfLine = 0;
    while(getline(file, crash))
    {
        std::cout << crash;
        nbrOfLine++;
    }
}
```

return 1 but my file contain 1500 lines.
thank you in advance

Comment: Check the file's character encoding. The functions and classes you are using expect 8-bit characters and probably ASCII. Give them something else and you could get weird results.

Comment: Use `getline(file, crash, '\r');`

Comment: Your `content` has lines separated by `\r` instead of `\n` or `\r\n`. If you want the output `file` to have *proper* line breaks, store the `content` into an `std::istringstream`, use `std::getline()` in a loop to read `\r`-delimited lines from that stream, and write each line to `file` using `\n` or `std::endl` for the line breaks.